# Silverstripe include vars into JS or CSS files

Tags: javascript, php, css, variables, silverstripe

I have found on Silverstripe website this custom js programmation :

https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/templates/requirements/

```
Requirements::javascriptTemplate("cms/javascript/editor.template.js", $vars);
```

At the end of the requirements, how $vars must be inserted and is this possible to do the same action to css files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the [api docs](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-Requirements_Backend.html#663-683) for the information which shows...

```
if($vars) foreach($vars as $k => $v) {
    $search[] = '$' . $k;
    $replace[] = str_replace("\\'","'", Convert::raw2js($v));
}

$script = str_replace($search, $replace, $script);
```

So the following array...

```
$vars = array(
    'iVal'  => '99',
    'iVal'  => "'string'",
);
```

would transform the following JavaScript...

```
var iVal = $iVal;
var sVal = $sVal;
```

to...

```
var iVal = 99;
var sVal = 'string';
```

Comment: Sweet I didn't know you could do this.  Also if you need to do complicated stuff in any text based file you can run any string (such as one that contains an entire js or css file) through the Silverstripe template engine and then store it back to disc or send it along as a custom css or js.

Comment: @ barry  : It works, but not as I expected. This code convert the file in inline javascript into the html. Is there are another way to change variables directly in a js file? no inline code into html

Comment: @NewbieSSProgrammer yeah you can also use customScript like this... Requirements::customScript("var myVar=".$iMyVar.";alert(myVar);");

Comment: @barry : yes i'm knowing this. But create a file like combined_files doing? Possible? A new file in themedir as example.

Comment: sorry @NewbieSSProgrammer I've answered as best as I can - I don't understand what you are asking for as an alternative... maybe a new question...?